# Swagger overrides Path-Annotations

Tags: jax-rs, swagger

I just got swagger to produces a valid swagger.json.
I configured swagger by using the Application-config method.
However, as soon as I override the getClasses-Method to add the swagger resouces, my JAX-RS Path-annotated classes stop working.
The method looks like this

```
@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();

    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    resources.add(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

    return resources;
}
```

and invoking super.getClasses() returns am empty set.
I got too many resources in my project, which I would not like to add manually.

Is there any way swagger does not mess with my previous configuration?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`javax.ws.rs.core.Feature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html). Just register the classes through the callback's `FeatureContext`. Annotating the feature with `@Provider` will have it registered through the scanning.

```
@Provider
public class SwaggerFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(ApiListingResource.class);
        context.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But note that if the application is already registering the resources and providers by class-path scanning, I imagine it should also pick up the Swagger classes, as they are annotated with `@Path`<sup>[**1**]</sup> and `@Provider`<sup>[**2**]</sup>. Those are the annotations the class-path scan looks for.

I haven't tried it myself (I stopped using class-path scanning<sup>[**3**]</sup>), but have you tried just not registering them at all? In theory the class-path scan should pick it up.

<sub>1. [io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/ApiListingResource.java#L39)

2. [io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/SwaggerSerializers.java#L19)

3. [When to Use JAX-RS Class-path Scanning Mechanism](https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/when_to_use_jax_rs)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, I got everything working now! Removing #getClasses did the trick, however, I am now registering every class on its on, as you suggested  as this seems the safer method.