# Swagger not generating the REST documentation

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, swagger

I'm trying to let Swagger autogenerate che documentation of my REST APIs but I only get a partial result.

I'm using Resteasy. I added the Maven Swagger dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I configured my Application object

```
package com.myapp.init;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource;
import io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers;


@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class WebappInit extends Application {

    public WebappInit() {
        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
        beanConfig.setHost("theIP:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/myapp/rest/");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("the.resource.package");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
        beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);

    }


    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();


        // here I add my REST WSs
        s.add(ApiListingResource.class);
        s.add(SwaggerSerializers.class);


        return s;
    }

}
```

Then I run the web application (on a Wildfly 9 server) and go to the URL `http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/swagger.json`. That's what I get

```
{
  swagger: "2.0",
  info: {
    version: "1.0.0"
  },
  host: "10.17.36.215:8080",
  basePath: "/devops/rest/",
  schemes: [
    "http"
  ]
}
```

It seems that Swagger cannot build the REST documentation, even though my REST endpoints are reachable and are added to the Swagger list of resources.

What can be the problem?

Thank you

Giulio

Update: I checked that in the Swagger init method `BeanConfig.classes()` my REST classes are correctly discovered.

Comment: What are you expecting to see in your swagger doc? As far as I can see your class `WebappInit` does not have any method marked with JAXRS annotations.

Comment: I'm expecting to see the list of my REST services with the useful data (HTTP methods, endpoints, request and response bodies) to use them. What do you mean with "As far as I can see your class WebappInit does not have any method marked with JAXRS annotations" ? In my WebappInit.getClasses() method I add the REST services class. Is not that enough?

Comment: I personally have never seen such technique. I believe this works for you, but I do not understand how. How do you call for example your `ApiListingResource` service? Using URL like `/rest/listing`?

Comment: Not sure if it's directly related to this problem, but you will have another problem, related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33710084/2587435). If you are class-path scanning for resources, you are disabling the class-path scanning, by simply registering the swagger classes.

Comment: @AlexR: I followed the Swagger guide for JAX-RS applications which extend the `Application` class: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-JAX-RS-Project-Setup-1.5.X

Comment: @peeskillet: ok thank you. But how should I register the Swagger classes?

Comment: Did you look at the answer?

Comment: Maybe a mistake on my part. I didn't notice the comment where you said you register the resource class. I thought you were class-path scanning for them. Disregard my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an @Api annotation to your resource classes.

For example:

```
package my.sample;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Api
@Path ("/mypath")
public class MyResource
{
    @GET
    public Response myEndpoint()
    {
        return Response.ok ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your problem. Your root service extends `Application` that allows dynamic building of your resources hierarchy. I believe that swagger even cannot support this technique because it generates its metadata (json files) at compile time.

I always use annotation based REST services, i.e. each resource is annotated with appropriate `@Path` annotation. The framework initializes all resources automatically, so I do not have to extend my root resource from `Application` and implement `getClasses()`. In this case swagger can extract all your resources and generate json files at compile time by analyzing of JAXRS annotations like `@Path`, `@PathParam`, `@GET`, `@POST` etc.

Comment: I'm annotating my REST classes with @Path and the other JAX-RS annotations but if I don't add the classes in the WebappInit.getClasses()  method they don't get discovered

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `@Api` annotation to your resource class and load the resource package in setResourcePackage method. It should do the magic.